# how to mention a user in slack message through the slack python API

Tags: python, slack-api

here is my code

```
  client.api_call(api_method='chat.postMessage', json={'channel': '#staff', 'text': f'{user} This is a test.'})
```

the output I get is

```
U046NKX4LSD This is a test.
```

It should rather mention the username and the username should get a notification as you mention @username.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://api.slack.com/reference/surfaces/formatting#mentioning-users

A mention is a special type of reference that will provide a link to the mentioned user's profile in the published text.

*To mention a user in app-published text, you need to provide their user ID in the following syntax:*

> Hey **<@U024BE7LH>**, thanks for submitting your report.